# Can different Quantum states produce the same measurement for a particular observable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to wrap my head around QM, so forgive me (and please correct me) if I my question or any way in which I explain the concepts as I understand them are wrong.

So this goes my understanding so far:

For a Hermitian operator $\mathcal{\hat A}$ representing the observable $\mathsf{A}$, the eigenfunctions of $\mathcal{\hat A}$, (let's call them $\psi_i$), are the different 'quantum states' (which are all the possible functions for the wave function $\Psi$ to collapse to, I think? sidenote: if that's the case would that mean that $\psi_i$ are not actually wave functions?) for which if you measure the system for the observable $\mathsf{A}$ you will definitely get $\psi_i$ for some particular $i$. And in fact the actual measurement you make is the eigenvalue of $\psi_i$, call it $a_i$. For two different eigenfunctions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$
 if  they have eigenvalues $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $a_1 \not= a_2$ then $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are orthogonal.

So my question is, if you have two different eigenfunctions $\psi_{n_1}$ and $\psi_{n_2}$ which have the same eigenvalue, $a_n$, then when you measure for $\mathsf{A}$,  can you get different quantum states (i.e either $\psi_{n_1}$ or $\psi_{n_2}$)?

And if the actual measurement you record is $a_n$, then how do you know which $\psi_{n_i}$ it corresponds to.

I guess I'm still not clear on what $\psi_i$ is REALLY representing, if after all it is the eigenvalue $a_i$ that we measure wouldn't the quantum state of the system be defined by $a_i$?

Thanks, and apologies in advance is my question is long winded or unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an eigenbasis for the operator $\mathcal{A}$. Let's say its eigenvalues $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^n$ are all non-degenerate (i.e. they are associated with only one eigenstate $\psi_i$) except for $a_0$, which is degenerate (i.e. it's associated with multiple nontrivial eigenstates $\{\phi_j\}_{j=1}^m$). Then, since any linear combination of the $\phi_j$ is also an eigenstate of $\mathcal{A}$ with the same eigenvalue $a_0$, there is a whole $m$-dimensional space of possible eigenstates.

If you measure $\mathsf{A}$ and get $a_0$ as a result, the "collapse" of the wavefunction is only partial. What's really happening is that the wavefunction you're measuring is *projected into* the $m$-dimensional eigenspace, so whatever $\phi_j$ components it had before measurement are all that's left.

For example, if we let $n=3$ and $m=2$, we write our wavefunction in this basis as

$$\Psi=c_1\psi_1+c_2\psi_2+c_3\psi_3+k_1\phi_1+k_2\phi_2$$

If you measure $\mathsf{A}$ and get $a_1$, then the wavefunction collapses into $\psi_1$, and likewise for $a_2$ and $\psi_2$, and $a_3$ and $\psi_3$. The coefficients $c_1,c_2,c_3$ determine the probability of measurement of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ (namely, the probability of measuring $a_1$ is $|c_1|^2$, etc.). If you measure $a_0$, then the wavefunction collapses into $k_1\phi_1+k_2\phi_2$ after measurement. Your probability of measuring $a_0$ is $|k_1|^2+|k_2|^2$.

Comment: Thank you! That helped with my understanding. What is $\psi_k$ if $a_k$ is the quantity we measure? And what conditions determine the degree to which the wavefunction collapses?

Comment: $\psi_k$ is the eigenstate of $\mathcal{A}$ associated with the eigenvalue $a_k$. It's uniquely determined by the diagonalization of $\mathcal{A}$. The degree to which the wavefunction collapses is determined by the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalues of $\mathcal{A}$ in whatever state space $\mathcal{A}$ operates on.

Comment: I understand that $\psi_k$ is the eigenstate of $\mathcal{A}$ mathematically, I meant what does it mean physically?

Comment: The eigenstate $\psi_k$ is a quantum state. Whether a quantum state is a physical object or merely a representation of non-determinism depends on the interpretation of quantum mechanics that you're using (and in some of those interpretations, "wavefunction collapse" isn't a thing).

Comment: Oh I see, I thought that it may be something that contained information on the other observable's of the system. So what happens to the information on the other observable's after it collapsed? Does it vanish?

Comment: Again, that depends on the interpretation you're using.